# didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame when trying to download file with wkwebview

Tags: swift, download, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView and on my page i have a button, that generates a pdf that is then offered for download., so when i click it in any browser it will immediatly start the download. I want that for wkwebview, too. I did some research and implemented the following:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    if !navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType {
        decisionHandler(.download)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.shouldPerformDownload {
        decisionHandler(.download, preferences)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = self
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = self
}

func download(_ download: WKDownload, decideDestinationUsing response: URLResponse, suggestedFilename: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(suggestedFilename)
        completionHandler(url)
    }
    
}
```

but when i click it, nothing happens and the console shows the following error:

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102, isMainFrame=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following delegate function:

```
func download(_ download: WKDownload, didFailWithError error: Error, resumeData: Data?) {
    print("webkit download fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

If you get the message "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -3000.)", the problem is most likely that you have an existing file with the same name in your download destination directory. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71926697/10953499).

You may also want to add the following delegate function to confirm if your file is actually downloaded:

```
func downloadDidFinish(_ download: WKDownload) {
    print("webkit download finished!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102, isMainFrame=1
```

And it turn out that I had an error in a WKURLSchemeHandler class that set a faulty minetype on the response